# Not being able to initialize condition variable in a struct

Tags: c, pthreads

Why am I not able to initialize a condition variable in a struct?
I want each node to have a condition variable so I can wait and signal it, and when I add the initialization code it throws this error:
expected ‘:’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘}’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘=’ token
make: *** [trie.o] Error 1

I tried doing the initializition when needed somewhere(not in the struct)and I still get an error, I have included pthreads.h

```
struct trie_node {

  pthread_cond_t condition=PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
};
```

Comment: What makes you think the error is even relevant to this piece of code? Why not post the stacktrace+source or the real problem instead of a vague guess?

Comment: @Shark Because everything worked fine, until I decided to add a member condition, which is initialized, and then it crashed with that error, when I remove the condition member then it is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To initialize when you define a struct trie_node object, use:

```
struct trie_node x = { …, PTHREAD_COND_INTIALIZER, … };
```

In place of the “…”, put initializers for other members of the struct, if any. You can omit the trailing ones if you do not care about them.

To assign a value to the `condition` member in an existing object, use:

```
x.condition = (pthread_cond_t) PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
```

Two things:

The code you used failed because you cannot specify the initialization of a member when you are defining the struct. Initialization goes with definitions of objects, not definitions of types.

The expansion `PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER` has the format of an initializer, something like `{ values }`. It is not an expression, so you cannot use it normally in an assignment statement. However, the `(pthread_cond_t) PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER` shown above creates a “compound literal” that is an expression.

Comment: if I have a condition variable in each node, and suppose I make a 5 nodes wait, then I want to signal a node, how would I know which thread to signal, do I have to keep track of all the condition variables? Suppose on a certain deletion, I want to signal thread 3, which is waiting(along with 7 others), how can I specifically signal thread 3? In my delete function, I don't know  A)How many threads are waiting(I can fix this with a count) B)what the condition variable for that thread waiting is

Comment: Sorry, different question, you should open a new Stack Overflow question for that.

Comment: Eric Postpischil I just did.

Comment: A strict reading of the standard indicates that PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER can only be safely used when the condition variable has static storage duration and is being initialized. Using a compound literal to assign PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER to a variable might work some of the time on some platforms, it might not work on others.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER` when initializing a structure member.

You have to use [`pthread_cond_init`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_cond_destroy.html) after you create an instance of the structure.

Actually, you can't initialize structure members *at all* in the structure definition, it's not just this one.

Comment: in my insert, I have an instance of the node, and when I use pthread_cond_init it throws this error, mutex-trie.c: In function ‘_insert’:
mutex-trie.c:185:31: error: request for member ‘condition’ in something not a structure or union
make: *** [mutex-trie.o] Error 1    --- What I did was         pthread_cond_init(node.condition, NULL);
 in my insert function, which takes a node as a parameter

Comment: @user2241639 If you read the linked reference, you will see that `pthread_cond_init` wants a _pointer_ to the structure, while you pass it by value. Use the address-of operator`&`:  `pthread_cond_init(&node.condition, NULL);`

Answer (score -1):

To initialize a structure member you have to create an instance of the structure as follows.

struct trie_node my_node;

Then you can initialize it like below.

my_node.condition=PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

OR

struct trie_node *my_node;
my_node->condition=PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

Comment: that does not work I get an error  mutex-trie.c:185:26: error: expected expression before ‘{’ token
make: *** [mutex-trie.o] Error 1